# Dark UISearchController iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am struggling really hard trying to reproduce this behaviour of the Files app on iPhone :

[Beginning behaviour of UISearchController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yba5d.png)

[End behaviour of UISearchController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAAsH.png)

So when we are clicking on the searchBar, the searchBar background stay white and the rest become dark.

But when I'm trying to reproduce this behaviour, I set this property to UISearchController:

```
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
```

I also tried with this property :

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
```

But my whole view is dark..

If anyone have ideas, could be great :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unclear what you are doing and (important) how what you get differs from what you want.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your result

Comment: Sure, the search bar is like this : https://www.noelshack.com/2018-07-3-1518647529-capture-d-ecran-2018-02-14-a-23-31-01.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `UIViewController` where you create your `UISearchController`. You need to set

`definesPresentationContext = true`

Otherwise, `UIKit` will infer the presentation context to be the root most view controller (for you likely your `UINavigationController`) and present the `searchResultController` on it causing it to cover top and bottom navigation bars.